# template library codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I have designed a template using the template library of codeigniter, the template has the following regions:

```
$template['template_ar']['template'] = 'template_ar';
$template['template_ar']['regions'] = array(
  'header',
  'title',
  'content',
  'topcontent',
  'sidebar',
  'footer',
  'options',
  'script',
);
```

I used the following code to render my template

```
class faq extends MY_Controller {
  /** 
  * Index
  * This function views the Home Page
  * 
  * @access  public
  * @return  
  */

  public function index() {
    $this->template->write_view('content','comment/questions');   
    $this->template->write('options','You one',TRUE);      
    $this->template->render();
  }
}
```

The problem that I want to eliminate is that I want to prevent the top content from appearing in my template. I need only the content, the header and the footer. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: can you share your library code here http://scrp.at/ to have look on it.

Comment: Which template library are you using? [williamsconcepts](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/) or [phil's](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template) or [another one](http://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+template)?

Answer (score 0):

**[Template Library for CodeIgniter](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/)**

**Set regions for writing to**

```
$this->template->set_regions($regions);
```

**Dynamically add region to the currently set template**

```
$this->template->add_regions($name, $props);
```

**Empty a region's content**

```
$this->template->empty_region($name);
```